# CodeceptJS, BDD, PageObjects, steps listed in output

Tags: bdd, codeceptjs

I'm currently evaluating CodeceptJS as an alternative to our heavy Java/Selenium/Cucumber stack. I have organized the project like so:

- BDD is used (everything starts with a feature file).
- Step definitions exist for each of the steps in the feature files.
- Step definitions use methods within a corresponding page object.

When I run the example project, I get output like this:

```
USER REGISTRATION --
  As someone who is not a member
  I would like the ability to sign up
  So that I can enjoy the benefits of Widget XYZ's services
  Register account from the signed out homepage
    Given I open the homepage 
      signedOutHomePage: open 
  ✔ OK in 3230ms
```

The above test is executed using:

```
npx codeceptjs run --steps
```

Is it possible to suppress the output of the Page Object (i.e. so the line `signedOutHomePage: open` is not diplayed)?

**UPDATE (another question):** Should I even use PageObjects if I'm using BDD?

Comment: You should avoid asking more than once question at a time. And it is OK to use page objects with BDD. I do it all the time. Can you post the code for the page object? Looks like something is writing to standard output, and that is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that whenever the `--steps` flag is used, any method calls in step definitions will be listed. Without the `--steps` flag, only the `Scenario` heading is displayed. It looks like there's no way around this. I'll create a feature request to the CodeceptJS team.